# Потерял текущую ветку с кодом - как восстановить?

Tags: android-studio, git, git-commit, git-push

У меня случился полный пиндец... Целую неделю писал код в **Android Studio** в базовой ветке **master**. Изменения коммитил, но не пушил на сервер.

В итоге, когда собрался запушить на сервер, решил сначала сохранить то что было на сервере в ветке **master** в отдельную ветку. Используя инструменты **AS**, в нижнем правом углу, выбрал ветку **master** на сервере, нажал **checkOutAs**, ввел новое имя "*develop/test1*" и нажал *enter*. После чего проект просто обнулился до состояния сервера, в папке проекта так же все файлы удалились, и пропала панель **Version Control**.

Вот последние сообщения в логах:

> 12:29 5 files committed: Отказался от использования элементов экшен бара
>
> 13:29 1 file committed: Схема базы данных
>
> 13:30 Checked out new branch develop/test1 from origin/master (show balloon)

Помогите понять что произошло. И самое главное - **как восстановить потерянный код**?! Где-то же дожна была сохраниться история коммитов???

Comment: Переключитесь обратно в локальный master и всего делов)

Comment: @vp_arth, как? Все инструменты связанные с этим исчезли... Напиши пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: git checkout master

Comment: `пропала панель Version Control` - вот это смущает, конечно. Точно не удаляли папку .git?

Comment: @vp_arth, спасибо огромное!!! Похоже это глюк AS. При переключении в master через терминал, панель vc опять отображается и там норм видно все ветки, в том числе и новую "develop/test1" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще один более простой и правильный способ решения проблемы.

По каким то непонятным причинам в **Android Studio** иногда слетает **Git**, что приводит к вышеописанным проблемам. И на самом деле, ничего переключать и восстанавливать не нужно. Достаточно зайти в меню **VSC** и нажать **Enable version control integration**, после чего в появившемся окошке выбрать нужный вариант (в моем случае Git).

Answer (score 5):

У вас все коммиты должны остаться в локальном репозитории. Попробуйте выполнить
`git reflog`, чтобы отобразить список всех сделанных вами коммитов.
Если найдете там нужный (последний ваш коммит), то сделайте `git checkout 1c7474c`, где "1c7474c" - это id нужного коммита.

Comment: Решилось переключением в мастер, через git checkout master, но этот способ тоже работает, проверял - нужные коммиты отображаются.

Comment: Минус этого способа в том, что вы остаётесь в опасном состоянии `detached HEAD`. Он работает, если локальной ветки больше нет(до запуска сборщика мусора), но необходимо сразу создать новую ветку.